# Javascript switch not sure if I am doing this correctly

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I have some JS where I have the variable $domain set by reading a cookie with cookie.getDomain.

What I am trying to do is use a switch, which I "think" is the correct way to do this. To set a predefined variable $gid if the $domain == to a specific domain. There will be a long list of domains and no domain shares the same gid and the gid can not be set in the cookie creation.

Here is what I came up with for an example. Is this even the correct way to be going about this? Thanks, if I need to post all of the code let me know and I will. But did not think it pertained to the question.

```
var gid = getGid();
switch (gid)
{
        case $domain == domain1.com:
                gid = "40";
        case $domain == domain2.com:
                gid = "42";
}
```

$domain section of the code

```
var domain = cookie.getDomain("$2");
```

Comment: That is _completely_ not the way `switch` works.  You need to learn Javascript.

Comment: @SLaks It's actually pretty close. While you're right that they probably need to learn a lot about the language, it's probably more useful to provide a link to help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to rearrange your switch statement, with the expression you want to compare with in the parentheses.

```
var gid;
switch (domain)
{
        case "domain1.com":
                gid = "40";
                break;
        case "domain2.com":
                gid = "42";
                break;
        default:
                gid = getGid();
}
```

Here's some information on switch statements in JavaScript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Also, if you've declared the variable for the domain as `domain`, you should refer to it later on as `domain` as well, instead of `$domain`, which would be a different identifier than `domain`.

Comment: Thanks this helped a bunch. To the others yes, I am new to JS and trying to learn switch right now. Thanks for pointing out my other mistake as well!

Answer (score 0):

You almost got there. Since @fernozzle already gave a good answer, here is an alternative:

```
var ListOfDomains   = {
    'domain1.com': 40,
    'domain2.com': 42,
    'domain3.com': 50,
    'domain4.com': 60
}
var gid = ListOfDomains[domain] || getGid();
```

Comment: Nice! I like how you did that, seems much cleaner to my n00b eyes. Thank you for the alternative.